# Why my code throw "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, svg

So i want to delete SVGs of my iframe, this is my code :

```
 var parent = document.querySelectorAll("#main");
 var child = parent[0].childNodes;
 var lengthOfNodes = child.length;

 for (var j = 0; j < lengthOfNodes; j++) {
      child[j].parentNode.removeChild(child[j]);
    }
```

`child` is an array of my svg element.

It works, but sometimes this algo throw me "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined" and i don't know why... I need to relaunch this algo to get it work.

Comment: You have 3 children and remove the first child. How many children do you have now? What do you think child[2] will be after you've removed a child? You do realise that childNodes is a live list, don't you?

Comment: @RobertLongson I was completly wrong... Thank you for precisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you remove a child, there is one less elements in the children array, so a loop like `for (let j=0; j<length; j++)` will make `j` too big at some point.

Prefer a code structured like this:

```js
// This code removes all <li> nodes
const parent = document.querySelector('ul');
// Converts parent.children to an array,
// then use forEach which automatically handles varying length
[...parent.children].forEach(child => parent.removeChild(child));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>xxx</li>
</ul>
```

Note that in order to wipe out the content of a parent node you might prefer the more simpler `parent.innerHTML = ''`!

Answer (score 2):

This way it would be too easy to remove elements you are iterating through
and take advantage of [refrences](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php)

```
var parent = document.querySelectorAll("#main");
var child = parent[0].childNodes;
child.forEach(c => c.remove());
```

or if you want to break from a loop somewhere in future then ForEach loop is not going to help then

```
var parent = document.querySelectorAll("#main");
var child = parent[0].childNodes;
for(var c of child){
//can get out of loop anytime
c.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the length of child itself in every iteration, Try this:

```
for (var i=0, j = child.length; i<j; i++) 
{
    child[i].parentNode.removeChild(child[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sup, and what do you think about a simple while loop instead of for loop ? Like this :

```
 var parent = document.querySelectorAll("#main");
 var child = parent[0].childNodes;
 var j = 0;

 while (obj.length > 0) {
   child[j].parentNode.removeChild(child[j]);
 }
```

Much easier for delete all elements. But if we want to iterate on a livelist with multiple conditions, we can do a reverse loop :

```
 for (var i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {     
   parent.removeChild(child[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

If the parent is undefined, at the moment you call parent[0] the array is empty. Are the SVG's being dynamically loaded? If so you might want to wrap this in a callback.